# Testing/mocking an orientation change in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, orientation

We're writing a mobile app using jQuery mobile and do most of the javascript debugging in Chrome.  One thing I can't test however is an orientation change, from portrait to landscape and vice versa.  I have to use a phone to fire that event, and am unable to debug the javascript window.orientationchange event without Chrome.

Or so it would seem.  Is there a way to mock this event in Chrome somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a desktop device doesn't have any real orientation changes, like mobile devices does have, it's no use to listen to `orientationchange`. You could simulate orientation by resizing the browser window though.

David Walsh wrote an article about this: http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change

Answer (score 1):

**A way to test your media queries based on orientation:**

The Window Resizer extension for Google Chrome enables you to view and test your site in either portrait or landscape orientation.  When installed, it has a size predefined of 320 x 480 and the orientation returned by jQuery using $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation() will be "portrait".  I added a new size of 480 x 320 for landscape and indicated a "Screen Type" of mobile.  In 480 x 320 size, the orientation returned by jQuery using $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation() will be "landscape".

This does not allow you to test the orientation change event specifically, but it is very useful for testing media queries based on orientation.