# Call a function when orientation changes

Tags: orientation

I want to call a function when orientation goes from portrait to landscape and vice versa.
I thought this would be very easy but having searched for hours and tried many versions out there I can't get this to work.
For simplicity's sake lets say I want to call a function called "change" when orientation changes and I want to do this in as few lines as possible in  tags directly in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work...

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", change);
```

Comment: This did not work and I don't know why. The function is called once the page is loaded but not on orientation change??

Comment: I don't think Chrome's device emulator fires that event if thats what you are using.  I had to use actual devices to test when building my site.  I think I used window resize in place of orientation change while developing.

Comment: Doesn't seem to.  Best to test on a real device.  You can use 'resize' to test your code in browser and then resize your window, but on Android popping up the keyboard fires the resize event, and that can lead to unwanted results. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051802/testing-mocking-an-orientation-change-in-chrome) for more.